# dotnet run --project <PATH> not taking project path as working directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

When using the .NET commands to run my Console App that is being stored on a network drive it sees the Working Directory as where it is being called from instead of the project path..

`dotnet run --project "\\network.drive\path\example\project"`

I get the output as follows:

```
WORKING DIRECTORY: C:\Windows\system32
Current Environment: DEV
Current Root URL: <API_URL>
Current Excel File:

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fileName
   at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String originalPath, String fullPath, String fileName, Boolean isNormalized)
   at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
   at MyProject.Reader.ReadAgentData(Int32 sheetIndex) in \\network.drive\path\example\project\Reader.cs:line 68
   at MyProject.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\network.drive\path\example\project\Program.cs:line 119
```

The error is the Excel File variable being an empty string. Since the working directory is not the path of the project, but instead `C:\Windows\system32` it cannot find the appsettings.json file that the information is pulled from.

Weirdly enough, using the command `dotnet watch --project "\\network.drive\path\example\project" run` causes the process to run correctly, it has the correct working directory and reads the appsettings.json file without issues, but then it obviously has to wait for a file change (the purpose of watch)..

How can I have my app recognize the Working Directory as the root of the project folder when using `dotnet run --project`?? (To be clear, I do NOT want to use watch unless I can have it end automatically)

Comment: Have a look at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5576). It seems, that UNC paths are not supported

Comment: I'm getting same issue with non-UNC paths

Answer (score -2):

Run dontet from the project's folder.

Because **appsettings.json** and ssh certificates are relative to the executiion folder.

Regardless of the System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location